# Symfony 4 : $form->getData() returns empty array where same array is filled in $request->request->all()

Tags: forms, symfony, post, request, symfony4

I'm facing a weird issue right now

Here is my code :

```
$data = [];

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($data, ["allow_extra_fields" => true,])
    ->add("attributes", FormType::class, ["allow_extra_fields" => true,])
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Save'])
    ->getForm();


$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $data = $form->getData();
    return new Response("<pre>".print_r($request->request->all(),1).print_r($data,1)."</pre>");
}
```

As you can see, for debug purposes, I'm displaying the whole $request->request and $form->getData().

Surprisingly, the first one is totally filled with correct information, the second one is empty.

I'm a bit lazy to censor the information in this array (company information) by hand so here is a censored screenshot of the result :

[image: Controller response]

Any idea why the form is not parsed ?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't see anything that will allow the form component to process your array of attributes.  I assume you have some kind of javascript thing going on inside the browser.  Maybe take a look at the [form collections type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html).

Comment: try `dump($form->getData(); exit();` instead

Comment: no way this will change anything

Answer (score 1):

the standard symfony `Form` class stores extra data in one place, the `extraData` property, which can be accessed via `getExtraData()`. This is obviously not particularly helpful in the case of sub forms (it would probably have to be called on the sub form then). I assume, the `allow_extra_fields` flag is primarily meant to prevent the form from erroring out in case of extra data, since nobody in their right mind would use the `Form` class for *no* fields (hence no validation, and none of the perks of using the form class in the first place). So your usage is ... "innovative".

The *proper* way to do it, would be to very well define the structure which `attributes` can have within your form (optionally with `required` set to `false`), solving most of the *actual* problems people try to solve with forms. - This is what forms are meant to be, an object that recursively handles the fields/sub forms. If you just want to ignore / circumvent that ... well

The improper way would be, to probably teach some form type - via some datamapper or datatransformer or event handling stuff - to handle any arbitrary data provided.

The easiest way to do it: just use `$request->request->all()` possibly a deserializer.

Comment: What if I have to validate it myself because fields are stored in a DB table and their attributes (values, required) are based on otherfields ? I mean if field A is not fileld, field B should not even be displayed. How am I supposed to do that on server side ? Ajax submit the form and send the subfields each time ? My network is crying already.

Comment: @JeanneD4RK I'm just saying the form component provides means to handle a very broad array of form processes that are very common overall. if you are fighting the form component at every step of your process, you might look for a different approach? you're certainly handling the frontend differently already, the form component can be brought to do many (even dynamic and data dependent) things (see event listeners, data mappers, data transformers, ...). In the end it's your choice. In general there's usually a somewhat standard and elegant approach. And I don't mean Ajax.

Comment: @JeanneD4RK In general I would agree. However, as far as I can tell, you currently do something halfway. You're halfway between raw data (you want a form that just takes an array) and happy object oriented form handling (you use a form component). I would suggest you decide for exactly one of them. Either you build a form that (even if not rendered) can take all the possible attributes. Or you just use `$request->request->all()` (or serialization). In either case, validation is probably better left for an object/class, that is cleanly defined and brings its own validation callbacks.

Comment: there probably isn't an infinite set of attributes that changes all the time ......

Answer (score 0):

I am using Symfony 6.4 and I had similar issue.

```
$myObject = $form->getData();
return new Response(json_encode(["aaa" => $myObject]));
```

returns empty object like `{"aaa":{}}`

However

```
$myObject = $form->getData();
$variable = $myObject->getMyProperty();
return new Response(json_encode(["aaa" => $variable]));
```

returns a value that I have submitted. So, I guess it doesn't have a serializer (that converts it into a string) and we think that it is empty while in fact there is an object. I believe if you or I used a debugger in an IDE we would see that the object was there.